# MySQL SELECT and Subset condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

So there are one major WHERE clause condition that I want my result from , but I have another condition such that I would like result that satisfy both conditions to appear first in the result array, follow by result that only satisfy the major condition. 
One possible way may be to do the selection based on the major result first and then manipulate using the second condition. But I would like to see if there is a way to do it by mysql select statement itself.

Comment: Can you show your current SQL? Or expected pseudo-code?

Comment: Give sql query for better understand

Comment: Union query on 2 selects.

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading your question, I understand that you don't want to filter results by second criteria, but to simply re-order them. In that case, use custom `ORDER BY`, something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE x = 'major'
ORDER BY (y = 'minor') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

use with block to multipal where close

> Blockquote

with 
t 
as
{

select * from table a where a.columnname = 1

},
p
as 
{

select * from table b where b.columnname = 2

}

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `with`. You have to use a view or temporary table.

Comment: This does not even seem valid SQL to me (and yes, I know that `WITH` clause is). Also I don't believe this can provide working solution any way you slice it

Comment: Who tell Is Not Valid it is helping with two whare clouse

Answer (score 0):

You can order by your conditions.

```
select some_columns 
  from a_table 
 where major_condition
 order by if(minor_condition, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Yeah I originally thought ORDER BY only work for numbers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It works for any data type but in my example the if-statement will actually give 1 or 0 to be used when ordering. You are basically creating a value to sort by, you can sort on other criteria after that if-statement as usual.